# SmartCapture Form not passing values to specified data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

We are attempting to use a smart capture form to pass our form values to a specified data extension within our ExactTarget account. The smart capture form is set to add to a data extension upon successful submission. As of now, the form completes, but the data is not passed through to our data extension. Any thoughts on why the data is not being passed? Here is the form that we have in place:

```
<form action="%%= RequestParameter('PAGEURL') =%%" method="POST">
    <div id="form-cont">
    <div class="input_ot_c">
        <div class="input_in_c lft-row" id="FirstName">
            <input type="text" maxlength="50" name="FirstName"  value="" size="75" placeholder="First Name"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input_ot_c">
        <div class="input_in_c" id="GraduationDate">
            <input type="text" maxlength="" name="GraduationDate"  value="" size="75" placeholder="Graduation Date" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input_ot_c">
        <div class="input_in_c lft-row" id="LastName">
            <input type="text" maxlength="50" name="LastName"  value="" size="75" placeholder="Last Name"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input_ot_c">
        <div class="input_in_c" id="PreferredStateofEmployment">
            <input type="text" maxlength="50" name="PreferredStateofEmployment" value="" size="75" placeholder="Preferred State of Employment"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lst_row">
        <div id="email" class="input_ot_c" id="wdth_cont">
            <div class="input_in_c lft-row" id="emailAddress">
                <input type="text" maxlength="250" name="EmailAddress" value="" size="75" placeholder="Email Address"/>
            </div>
        </div>  

            <div id="button_cont" id="input_button">

                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Download"/>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>  

    <!-- AMP Processing Placeholders DO NOT REMOVE -->
    <input type="hidden" name="__successPage" id="__successPage" value="http://www.google.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__errorPage" id="__errorPage" value="http://www.yahoo.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__contextName" id="__contextName" value="FormPost" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__executionContext" id="__executionContext" value="Post" />
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the stylesheets being applied to the smart capture form made the form variables error upon submission. To achieve a styled form we had to create a content area and apply the styling to that div.